# JAXB don't generate attribute from java class

Tags: xml, jaxb

I have a class like the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "task")
class Task{
  @XmlElement(name = "id")
  Integer id;
  @XmlElement(name = "name")
  String name;
  String bzId;
}
```

I want to generate an xml like the following:

```
<task>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>String</name>
</task>
```

I can't seem to find it anywhere. How can i not generate the "bzId" in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the `@XmlTransient` annotation. Same this as the transient keyword, but for xml :D.

You can also use the [`@XmlAccessorType`](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/jaxb-annotations.xtp) on the class to change the default behaviour and just serialize annotated attributes.

Comment: thanks Augusto, this is just what i needed i will use the @XmlAccessorType after all because i will wrap the task in a <tasks> tag so no need for the XmlRootElement...the link in your answer is great, thanks for that as well